Eliminating left recursive nonterminals without adding $\epsilon$-productions
I have been reading the book "Compiler Construction" written by William M. Waite and Gerhard Goos. I found a statement in the chapter "5.3.2. Top-Down Analysis and LL(k) Grammars" whose proof is not given and I cannot manage to completely understand the reasoning behind.
The statement is part of the section that describes an algorithm for eliminating left recursive nonterminals from a CFG (namely Theorem 5.25). The algorithm from the book is the following:

For every context-free grammar $G = (T, N, P, Z)$ with left recursive nonterminals, there exists an equivalent grammar $G' = (T, N', P', Z)$ with no left recursive nonterminals.
Let the elements of $N$ be numbered consecutively: $N = \{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$. If we choose the indices such that the condition $i<j$ holds for all productions $X_i \to X_j \omega$ then $G$ has no left recursive nonterminals. If such a numbering is not possible for $G$, we can guarantee it for $G'$ using the following construction:

Let $N' = N, P' = P$. Perform steps (2) and (3) for $i = 1, \dots, n$.
For $j = 1, \dots, i-1$ replace all productions $X_i \to X_j \omega \in P'$ by $\{X_i \to \chi_j\omega | X_j \to \chi_j \in P'\}$
Replace the entire set of productions of the form $X_i \to X_i \omega \in P'$ (if any exist) by the productions $\{B_i \to \omega B_i | X_i \to X_i \omega \in P'\} \cup \{B_i \to \epsilon\}$, adding a new symbol $B_i$ to $N'$. At the same time, replace the entire set of productions $X_i \to \chi, \chi \neq X_i \gamma$ by $X_i \to \chi B_i$. The symbols added during this step wil be given numbers $n+1, n+2, \dots.$


Then the statement that I do not understand the reasoning behind follows:

If the string $\omega$ in the production $X_i \to X_i\omega$ does not begin with $X_j, j \leq i$ then we can replace $X_i \to X_i \omega$ by $\{B_i \to \omega,  B_i \to \omega B_i\}$ and $X_i \to \chi$ by $\{X_i \to \chi, X_i \to \chi B_i\}$ in step (3).

Why is the condition "if the string $\omega$ in the production $X_i \to X_i\omega$ does not begin with $X_j, j \leq i$" required? I thought that maybe if that condition is not satisfied there are cases where we are adding some cycles again by using these productions instead of the ones in the algorithm. But additional cycles that we could add would require that there exist some $\epsilon$-productions (i.e. there is some production $X_i \to \chi$, where $\chi = \epsilon$), but I believe the algorithm assumes there are no $\epsilon$-productions in the original grammar (because if there were, we could have "hidden" left recursion, and the algorithm does not seem to solve it). Furthermore, even if the original grammar had $\epsilon$-productions, if the "improved" version of the algorithm (the one that does not add more $\epsilon$-productions) were to add new cycles, the original ones would do so as well.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain what is the reasoning behind the condition in the quoted statement. Thank you!
